# Trigger jQuery mouseout event on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I have a button and some sublinks for a page viewed on the iPad...Now when I click on the button, I want to trigger a mouseout event on the sublinks (purpose is to remove hover state from the link)

I have tried

```
$("#leftNav  a").mouseleave(); 
$("#leftNav  a").mouseout(); 
$("#leftNav  a").trigger("mouseout"); 
$("#leftNav  a").trigger("mouseleave");
```

But none of them seem to be working and they do not on the iPad. Please help me. Thank you.

Before you say, there is no hover on iPad, I am aware...But please read this from Apple;

> ```
> When the user focuses on an element by single-tapping it, the
> ```
>
> :hover styles are applied and the mouseover, mousemove, mousedown,
>   mouseup and click events fire (always; and in that order).

Comment: Out of curiosity, where and in what way did you call those triggers?

Comment: The list from Apple are the events dispatched when a user touches an element. The list does not include "mouseout" or "mouseleave". Where does it say that those events are supported, i.e. that elements have handlers for those event types?

Comment: That is a point I never get. Why not work with the touch-events, either through custom eventListeners or through a jQuery-plugin, but instead try to emulate behavior that doesn't exist? It's like reinventing the wheel in triangular shape instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience it is more like:

```
:hover styles are applied and the mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup and click 
events fire (always; and in that order) 
or NONE OF THE ABOVE AT ALL.
```

Did you consider working with a plugin that's supporting touch events?

Comment: Wel...i do not know what difference a plugin would make...anyways i m looking to do this completely using jQuery only..

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this page :
[iPad plug-ins for Jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ipad)

It will have the correct syntaxes you'll need.

Comment: Well the syntax is correct....the issue is the iPad is not triggering the mouseout event...